# Encode OpenCV/NumPy image into Tensorflow string(Python)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, tensorflow

I have some tensorflow code that works with a string representation of an image as read from a file by the `tf.gfile.Gfile` function `read()`, which, according to the documentation, "Returns the contents of a file as a string.". Looking at the code, it does a `sess.run()` on a `feed_dict={"image_feed:0": encoded_image}` where `encoded_image` is the value passed directly from the `read()` function.

I want to be able to pass previously `imread` images in the form of `np.ndarray`s into this function, which would require me to convert them to this string format, without having to write the images to the disk, which would be slow.

I have a network that is already finalized, so I can't just `tf.image.encode_png()` the `np.ndarray` containing the image, because that gives me `RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.`. Is there a way to convert a `ndarray` directly into this string format to feed it into the network, without creating a new tensor every time I need to feed an image to the net?

Comment: Can you run `tf.image.encode_png` on the `np.ndarray` in a separate graph/session? Then feed the result of that `encoding_session.run` call to the finalized network. Somewhat annoying, but the alternative seems to be calling the op kernel for `tf.image.encode_png` yourself.

Comment: That's the method I considered as well, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.